# Error in getting values into my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in accessing server side value into my jQuery function. I gave my localhost path (NewsRecord.php) as the AJAX URL (it is working) but if I give server path it is not working... I don't know what is the problem -- the server URL prints the JSON data properly. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>News Letter</h1>
    </div>
<div data-role="content" id="level" ></div>

<div data-role="footer"></div>
    <h4>Powered by Handigital</h4>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $.ajax({
                url:'NewsRecord.php',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(output) {
                for(var u=0;u < output.length;u++)
                {
                $('#level').append('<div>Title &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:'+output[u].Title+'<br>Source  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<a href='+output[u].links+'>'+output[u].Source+'</a><br>Category :'+output[u].Category+'</div><hr>');
                }}
                );
        });     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Syntax error to start with. You need to put for loop inside a function.

Comment: Is success-callback even called? What is the result of `console.dir(output)`?

Comment: dont use `.ready()` in jQM http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your `for()` loop in a function. This function can be given to the `success` property of the ajax method, where it will be called when the ajax call is complete (and is successful):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'NewsRecord.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output){
            for (var u = 0; u < output.length; u++) {
                $('#level').append('<div>Title &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:' + output[u].Title + '<br>Source  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<a href=' + output[u].links + '>' + output[u].Source + '</a><br>Category :' + output[u].Category + '</div><hr>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry i didnt copied properly problem is not that...the above code is running properly but if i give server url in ajax url path it is not working.. i dono the problem is from my side or server side